# Javascript Object order incorrect

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I have got a function which retrieves an object.

This object has a property and a value. The property is numeric and starts at "-30" all the way up to "50"

The problem is that when I loop through this object the browser seems to order it starting at "0" instead of starting at the initial property of "-30"

I need to make sure the order is exactly the same as the object.

```
var colorOj = {
   "-30":"#111","-29":"#131313", ..etc.., "0":"#333", ..etc.., 
   "50":"#555"
}

function makeList(object){
   for (var i in object) {
      console.log(i); // Returns 0,1,2,3,4,5
      // I need a return of -30,-29,-28,..., 0, 1, 2 ...
   }
}
makeList(colorObj);
```

Comment: Properties in JS objects [don't have any specific order](https://es5.github.io/#x12.6.4). You've to convert your object to array to get a sortable "object".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-javascript-object-by-property-value/16794116#16794116

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @Teemu, properties are not stored in any specific order. But you can print them in any order using specific sort function accordingly.

#### Code

```js
var obj = {};

for (var i = 5; i > -5; i--) {
  obj[i * 10] = i * 10;
}

// Sort and get all keys...
var keys = Object.keys(obj).sort(function(a, b) {
  return parseInt(a) - parseInt(b);
});

console.log(keys)

// Loop over keys to print values of each property
keys.forEach(function(item) {
  console.log(item, obj[item]);
})
```

Comment: Many thanks, how would I then get the value of each Key based on your code?

Comment: `keys` is an  array of all keys in sorted order. You will have to loop over it to get its value. I have already done that in above code.

Comment: I meant to get the value of "#333"...

Comment: If you know the ID, then instead of looping, just write `obj[ID]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this maybe:

```
var colorOj = {
   "-30":"#111","-29":"#131313", "0":"#333", 
   "50":"#555"
};

var keys = Object.keys(colorOj).sort(function(a,b){return a - b})

for(var i = 0; i < keys.length;i++){console.log(keys[i])}
```

This way you can get every key in the object. Then sort it however you like(the sort function in javascript can take a compare function as a parameter look -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)